# I am not sure what to do regarding this error

Tags: python, typeerror

I'm trying to write a class for a particular problem. I keep getting the same error always

I've tried to use '//' instead of '/' but that doesn't seem to work

```
import numpy as np
myRes = 0.1

class Map(object):

    def __init__(self, origin_x = 0.0, origin_y = 0.0, resolution =myRes, width = 30.0, height = 30.0):
        self.origin_x = origin_x
        self.origin_y = origin_y
        self.resolution = resolution
        self.width = width / resolution
        self.height = height / resolution
        self.grid = 0.5 * np.ones((height // resolution, width // resolution), dtype=np.uint8)
```

When I initialize the class I keep getting the same error:

> TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
>    in ()
>   ----> 1 A = Map()
>
> 1 frames
>    in **init**(self, origin_x, origin_y, resolution, width, height)
>         8         self.width = width / resolution
>         9         self.height = height / resolution
>   ---> 10         self.grid = 0.5 * np.ones((height // resolution, width // resolution), dtype=np.uint8)
>
> /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/numpy/core/numeric.py in ones(shape, dtype, order)
>       221 
>       222     """
>   --> 223     a = empty(shape, dtype, order)
>       224     multiarray.copyto(a, 1, casting='unsafe')
>       225     return a
>
> TypeError: 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

Comment: You're making us guess where the error is.  Please update the question with the full error traceback message.

Comment: Updated. Thanks for letting me know

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you're feeding `np.ones` a pair of truncated floats, but you promised it `int` values:

```
np.ones((height // resolution, width // resolution), dtype=np.uint8)
```

The results of those divisions are `float` values, not integers.  Yes, they're truncated, but still are floats, such as 2.0 or 299.0.  Instead, convert them:

```
np.ones((int(height / resolution), int(width / resolution)), dtype=np.uint8)
```

The double-slash operator `//` returns the truncated value as you seem to expect, but the data type remains float if either operand is a float:

```
>>> 1.5 // 0.5
3.0
>>> 1.5 // 0.6
2.0
>>> 1 // 0.5
2.0
>>> 5 // 2
2
>>> 5.0 //2
2.0
>>> 11 // 3.0
3.0
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Appreciate the help! I was wondering if I should use int() or just //. I guess int() should have been the way

Answer (score 1):

`np.ones` function needs integers as arguments. You can convert them to `int` like this:

```
np.ones((int(height // resolution), int(width // resolution)), dtype=np.uint8)
```